# What is a cluster in Solana terminology?

Tags: cluster

What is considered a cluster in Solana terminology? Is this just another name for RPC node where anyone can request and send transactions to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A Solana cluster is a set of validators working together to serve
> client transactions and maintain the integrity of the ledger. Many
> clusters may coexist. When two clusters share a common genesis block,
> they attempt to converge. Otherwise, they simply ignore the existence
> of the other. Transactions sent to the wrong one are quietly rejected.
> In this section, we'll discuss how a cluster is created, how nodes
> join the cluster, how they share the ledger, how they ensure the
> ledger is replicated, and how they cope with buggy and malicious
> nodes.

from [Solana docs](https://docs.solana.com/cluster/overview)